# Using multiple rules in moment-recur.all not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, moment-recur

I'm using the `moment-recur` package and I'm trying to create an array of all dates that occur according to some rules. For that I'm using
`recurrence.all("L")`.

Calling this method with the next object returns an empty array:

```
{
  start: moment.utc("2018-01-04T22:00:00.000+00:00"),
  end: moment.utc("2019-01-04T22:00:00.000+00:00"),
  rules:
      [ { measure: 'daysOfWeek', units: { '0': true, '1': true, '5': true}},
      { measure: 'weeks', units:{ '2': true }  } ],
  exceptions: [],
  units: null,
  measure: null,
  from: null 
}
```

How can I make it work? Is there any other method that handles multiple rules?

Thank you!